# SQL IIS application login fails for user

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-applications, iis-7

I am scratching my head here and I need a hand with this.  Please save my sanity!
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4a9p.png)

I can log into SSMS with the username and it works.

I can open the ODBC/System DSN and test the connection using the same username and it works.
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKOxA.png)

I have the vtimecard.ini configured with the username and password IDENTICAL to the login for SQL and that used for the 2 logins that work...

```
[ODBC]
DSN=
Driver=SQL Server
Server=MLAERP01\VTIMECARD
Database=vTimeCard
UID=vtc2
PWD=
```

BUT once I try to access the website, it fails.

Details: Global database error Open (global): 'Login failed for user 'vtc2'.' (D=, D=SQL Server, S=MLAERP01\VTIMECARD, D=vTimeCard, U=vtc2)

and when I check the SQL server log it gives:

Login failed for user 'vtc2'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: ] Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8

Please direct me what I need to look at with this.  I am not that versed in SQL and webApps.  Any help is good help!

Comment: Fails with what error? P.S. you've not specified a DSN (Data Source Name) in the ini file

Comment: I was unable to post pictures due to my reputation...

Details:
Global database error
Open (global): 'Login failed for user 'vtc2'.'
(D=, D=SQL Server, S=MLAERP01\VTIMECARD, D=vTimeCard, U=vtc2)

and when I check the SQL server log it gives:
Login failed for user 'vtc2'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <server's IP address>]
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.